# Get focus back in textField from other frame in java

Tags: java, jframe

I have two `JFrames`, when clicked on a `textField` in Parent `form` a small `form` appears with `focus` on it's `textField`, on process when this current `form` disappears, I want to get `focus` back on the Parent form's `textField`, that is explained in the images below, how can I do that?

```
IMAGE
```

[image]

Wha I did is tried to take focus by `requestFocus()` method to Parent form's `textField` as below!

```
CODE FOR SMALL WINDOW

quantityField.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && priceField.getText().length() > 0) {
                if (containsOnlyNumbers(priceField.getText())) {
                    productPrice = Double.parseDouble(priceField.getText());
                    productQuantity = Double.parseDouble(quantityField.getText());
                    TaxInfo tax = taxeslogic.getTaxInfo(oProduct.getTaxCategoryID(), m_oTicket.getCustomer());
                    addTicketLine(new TicketLineInfo(oProduct, productQuantity, productPrice, tax, (java.util.Properties) (oProduct.getProperties().clone())));
                    status = true;
                    jProductList.requestFocusInWindow();
                    frame.dispose();
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid value entered!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                TaxInfo tax = taxeslogic.getTaxInfo(oProduct.getTaxCategoryID(), m_oTicket.getCustomer());
                addTicketLine(new TicketLineInfo(oProduct, dMul, dPrice, tax, (java.util.Properties) (oProduct.getProperties().clone())));
                status = true;
                jProductList.requestFocusInWindow();
                frame.dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

CODE FOR PARENT FORM

```
jProductList.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                if (jProductList.getSelectedIndex() < 0) {
                    //Do nothing
                } else {
                    //Add product into list
                    m_returnObj = (ProductInfoExt) product.getProductDetail(product.getProductCode(jProductList.getSelectedItem().toString()));
                    jProductList.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                    if (addTicketLine(m_returnObj, 1.0, m_returnObj.getPriceSell())) {
                        System.out.println("Requesting focus");
                        jProductList.requestFocusInWindow();
                    }
                    //jProductList.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

WHERE `jProductList` is the Parent form's textField I need to get focus on!

Answer (score 0):

> I have two JFrames,

An application should only have a single JFrame. In your case the child window should be a `modal JDialog`.

> when clicked on a textField in Parent form a small form appears

Don't use a KeyListener.

You should add an ActionListener to the text field in the parent form. The ActionListener will be invoked when the Enter key is pressed.

Focus will then automatically go back to the text field when the modal dialog is closed.

In the child form you again should not be using a KeyListener. You can again add an ActionListener to the text field. To handle the Escape key you should be using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).